# java recursively reversing an array of characters

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am struggling with a problem that requires me to reverse an array of characters in Java, using a recursive helper function. I was able to reverse an array of integers rather easily, but I keep getting an overflow error when I run this code trying to reverse an array of chars:

```
public static void reverseArray (char[] a) {
    reverseArrayHelper(a, 0, a.length-1);
}

public static void reverseArrayHelper(char[] a, int lower, int upper) {
    char temp = 'a';
    if(lower < upper) {
        temp = a[lower];
        a[lower]=a[upper];
        a[upper]=temp;
        reverseArrayHelper(a, lower++, upper--);
    }
}
```

If someone can help me understand where I am wrong with this code I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You need to put the `++`/`--` in front of the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `lower++` and `upper--`, use `lower + 1` and  `upper - 1`. Alternatively, you can use `++lower` and `--upper`. Postfix increment and decrement operators assign the value first and then change the value i.e. effectively, you are passing the same value of `lower` and `upper` to `reverseArrayHelper` each time.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        char[] chars = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
        reverseArray(chars);
        System.out.println(new String(chars));
    }

    public static void reverseArray(char[] a) {
        reverseArrayHelper(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    public static void reverseArrayHelper(char[] a, int lower, int upper) {
        char temp;
        if (lower < upper) {
            temp = a[lower];
            a[lower] = a[upper];
            a[upper] = temp;
            reverseArrayHelper(a, lower + 1, upper - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
edcba
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){        
    char[] charArray = {'a','e','d','c','b'};
     reverseArray(charArray);
 }       
  public static void reverseArray (char[] a) {
        reverseArrayHelper(a, 0, a.length-1);
 }
  public static void reverseArrayHelper(char[] a, int lower, int upper) { 
   if(lower < upper) {
   char temp = a[lower];
    a[lower]=a[upper];
    a[upper]=temp;
    reverseArrayHelper(a, ++lower, --upper);
}   
System.out.print(a);
}
}
```